# Google mobile vision not working in China

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-services, google-vision

We have successfully implemented the Google mobile vision scanner in our android apps but scanner does not work when app is used in china.

It says following error : - "Sorry, your device does not support the Google play service.".

This same apk works fine when installed in another country and devices.

Answer (score 2):

in China ,if you want to use google,you need VPN.Google service can't work in usually devices,it was ban

Comment: If we want to use it then, is there any way??

Comment: you can  install Google play seservice，and use vpn .in China we do this,if we want use any google's thing